# ServiceStack Text setting to infer primitive values types while deserializing json

Tags: servicestack, jsonserializer, servicestack-text

I have a json which is generated on runtime with x amount of properties and for this reason I can't use a POCO to deserialize it e.g.

```
"{"UserId": 1234,"Name": "Adnan","Age": 30, "Salary": 3500.65}"
```

The best option for me is to deserialize it in `Dictionary<string,object>`

I am using ServiceStack `JsonSerializer` to deserialize the json to a `Dictionary<string,object>` which works fine, but when I try to get types of the objects in the dictionary they do not match accordingly.

I have tried the following:

If I don't use the following options all dictionary object values are inferred as `strings`

```
JsConfig.ConvertObjectTypesIntoStringDictionary = true;
JsConfig.TryToParsePrimitiveTypeValues = true;
```

When I use the above options, all `Int64` and `Double` values are inferred as `Decimal` values.

Is there any option to change this, so that primitive values are inferred as `Int64` or `Double` instead of `Decimal`

Ps: I have no requirement that it needs to be exact type i.e. `Int32` if it falls under that bracket.

I have tried using Json.Net and it works fine and the object values are inferred as `Int64` and `Double`, but as I am using ServiceStack `JsonSerializer` in my project would be good to know how this can be achieved using that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Set `TryToParseNumericType = true`

You need to set `JsConfig.TryToParseNumericType = true` if you want ServiceStack.Text to determine the type beyond a `decimal` type.

## Controlling the primitive types:

With regard to controlling the types that your numbers are parsed to, I submitted changes to improve ServiceStack.Text, to provide such functionality which will be included in an upcoming release, [with this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/commit/50cc842e1c21dac9c29788f2a6b561acd38fb3d5).

So you will be able to do:

```cs
JsConfig.TryParseNumericType = true;
JsConfig.ParsePrimitiveFloatingPointTypes = ParseAsType.Single;
JsConfig.ParsePrimitiveIntegerTypes = ParseAsType.Int32 | ParseAsType.Int64;
```

That configuration would return an `Int32` instead of a `byte`, as you indicated was a problem. And instead of `decimal` you would get a `float`.

### For reference:

Below is the updated primitive parsing method, which should now provide better control, and better fallback options when types cannot be parsed.

```cs
public static object ParsePrimitive(string value)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value)) return null;

    bool boolValue;
    if (bool.TryParse(value, out boolValue)) return boolValue;

    // Parse as decimal
    decimal decimalValue;
    var acceptDecimal = JsConfig.ParsePrimitiveFloatingPointTypes.HasFlag(ParseAsType.Decimal);
    var hasDecimal = decimal.TryParse(value, NumberStyles.Number, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out decimalValue);

    // Check if the number is an Primitive Integer type given that we have a decimal
    if(hasDecimal && decimalValue == decimal.Truncate(decimalValue))
    {
        // Value is a whole number
        if (JsConfig.ParsePrimitiveIntegerTypes.HasFlag(ParseAsType.Byte) && decimalValue <= byte.MaxValue && decimalValue >= byte.MinValue) return (byte)decimalValue;
        if (JsConfig.ParsePrimitiveIntegerTypes.HasFlag(ParseAsType.SByte) && decimalValue <= sbyte.MaxValue && decimalValue >= sbyte.MinValue) return (sbyte)decimalValue;
        if (JsConfig.ParsePrimitiveIntegerTypes.HasFlag(ParseAsType.Int16) && decimalValue <= Int16.MaxValue && decimalValue >= Int16.MinValue) return (Int16)decimalValue;
        if (JsConfig.ParsePrimitiveIntegerTypes.HasFlag(ParseAsType.UInt16) && decimalValue <= UInt16.MaxValue && decimalValue >= UInt16.MinValue) return (UInt16)decimalValue;
        if (JsConfig.ParsePrimitiveIntegerTypes.HasFlag(ParseAsType.Int32) && decimalValue <= Int32.MaxValue && decimalValue >= Int32.MinValue) return (Int32)decimalValue;
        if (JsConfig.ParsePrimitiveIntegerTypes.HasFlag(ParseAsType.UInt32) && decimalValue <= UInt32.MaxValue && decimalValue >= UInt32.MinValue) return (UInt32)decimalValue;
        if (JsConfig.ParsePrimitiveIntegerTypes.HasFlag(ParseAsType.Int64) && decimalValue <= Int64.MaxValue && decimalValue >= Int64.MinValue) return (Int64)decimalValue;
        if (JsConfig.ParsePrimitiveIntegerTypes.HasFlag(ParseAsType.UInt64) && decimalValue <= UInt64.MaxValue && decimalValue >= UInt64.MinValue) return (UInt64)decimalValue;
        return null;
    }

    // Value is a floating point number

    // Return a decimal if the user accepts a decimal
    if(hasDecimal && acceptDecimal)
        return decimalValue;

    // Parse as double if decimal failed or user wants a double
    double doubleValue = 0;
    var acceptDouble = JsConfig.ParsePrimitiveFloatingPointTypes.HasFlag(ParseAsType.Double);
    var hasDouble = (!hasDecimal || acceptDouble) && double.TryParse(value, NumberStyles.Float, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out doubleValue);

    // Return a double if the user accepts a double
    if(acceptDouble && hasDouble)
        return doubleValue;

    // Parse as float
    float floatValue;
    var acceptFloat = JsConfig.ParsePrimitiveFloatingPointTypes.HasFlag(ParseAsType.Single);
    var hasFloat = float.TryParse(value, NumberStyles.Float, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out floatValue);

    // Return a float if the user accepts a float
    if(acceptFloat && hasFloat)
        return floatValue;

    // Default to decimal, then double , then float or null
    if(hasDecimal) return decimalValue;
    if(hasDouble) return doubleValue;
    if(hasFloat) return floatValue;
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Scott, when I use the above mentioned option it seems to work fine for `Int` values but for `Float` and `Double` values it is still inferring it as `Decimal`.

Comment: @adnangohar Yeah I think this parse method may be slightly flawed because most `float`s and `double` as strings can be parsed into `decimal` but not the other way around. So the order of the checks lets it down here. I guess this would be a bug that needs to be addressed.

Comment: @adnangohar I have queried this with the ServiceStack team.

Comment: thanks for the help. One more thing which I noticed was that if I use `"UserId": 123` it gets parsed as `Byte` and similarly as the int value increases it starts getting parsed in a bigger `Int` value. It would be good if we could have some setting where we could dictate that integer values should be inferred as `Int64` or `Int32` and similar for `Float` and `Double` values.

Comment: @adnangohar I spoke with the ServiceStack author and he says this code was authored by a contributor, anyway, he agreed that the testing for floats and doubles needed to come before the decimal checks. But the general consensus is floating point is nasty :/ [It's been fixed in this commit.](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/commit/0c00ba8a08c7e18ff58c2cac0c33eb6804c8e69b).

Comment: @adnangohar [I have submitted a pull request](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/pull/428) to try and resolve the type preference issues. If this is accepted then it will be possible to specify your preference of types. *More information about how it will work in the pull request*. Feel free to comment there and provide your input.

Comment: thanks for the help and update. I agree that floating points are more tricky to handle. I will grab the latest and give it a go. Will surely provide my input on the type preference issue.

Comment: @adnangohar [New pull has gone in](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/pull/429). It addresses some thoughts Demis had.

Comment: @adnangohar I have updated the answer to reflect the change made to ServiceStack.Text that now provides the missing functionality you required to control the returned primitive type. I hope this addresses the issues in your question.

Comment: thank you I tried it and it works well. If I encounter any issue I will post it under the github link.